# How to listen to Client Side events on Server Side

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm working with the HTML5 Video element.

I'm using JavaScript to work with the video element and check if they watched the entire video.

But my issue is that once the video is finished "onended", I need to trigger a c# function that will update my database that they watched the video.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to call a c# function from JavaScript where I'm doing my testing and gave up.

Is it possible to listen for Client Side events from the server side? That way i could listen for "onended" and once the event is fired I could use it to update the database. Or is there a way to create server side events for the video element?

Comment: `Is it possible to listen for Client Side events from the server side? ` That's the very definition of what a server is there to do!

Comment: @mason upvote for witty comment

Comment: @mason Haha you got me...now seriously.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to listen for Client Side events from the server side?

Yes. By using client-side (JavaScript) events to call your server side events.

Using jQuery and ASP.NET Web API as an example, it would be something like below:

```
// Server-Side
public void VideoWatcherController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void RegisterWatchedVideo([FromBody]string id)
    {
        // do server side actions here.
    }
}

// Client Side
$('#yourVideoElement').on('ended', function() {
    $.post('http://yourwebsitename.com/api/VideoWatcher', userId);
});
```

Few warnings though. Beware of [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) in accessing your Web API from a different domain. And beware of IE restrictions with regards to the video tag.

**ADDITIONAL EXPLANATION** for why `http://yourwebsitename.com/api/VideoWatcher` is used:

The default route for ASP.NET Web API is `api/{controller}/{id}` (where id is optional). Note that there is no `{action}` there.

**Question:** *How does the route now which action/method in the controller to use?*

The answer is in the HTTP verb used. 
Thus, since we are using POST here, then the route looks for the action/method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.
More info [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: That should be a POST, not a GET, since it's modifying state on the server.

Comment: Don't you also need to specify the controller action in your callback POST URL?

Comment: @im1dermike No, because I'm basing it on the default routing for Web API: `api/{controller}/{id}` (where id is optional)

Comment: Ah.  So it's only `{controller}/{action}/{id}` for non-API controllers?

Comment: @im1dermike for MVC controllers, yes

Comment: @im1dermike It's whatever you want it to be. The default for MVC is `{controller}/{action}/{id}` and the default for Web API is `api/{controller}/{id}`. But changing it only requires typing a few characters into a string.

Comment: yes @mason . but for the sake OP. i made it look like the default because he might copy-paste it into his code. (aren't we supposed to help them? :))

Comment: @IanChuTe I understand and upvoted your question. I just wanted OP to understand the "default" just means whatever the templates came with, and that otherwise the defaults are not special in any way.

Comment: @michaelhanon I think you're using it the wrong way. Better read some guides :) is that Web API?